# Ethernet cable stuck in laptop

Tags: laptop, ethernet, cable

An ethernet cable is stuck in the laptop. The laptop is a Lenovo G50 and its Ethernet port is compact and sort of expands when you push the cable in. The cable is thinner and narrower than most, but the actual terminal seems to be standard. This has never happened before. I've tried really hard to get it out but it won't move. This is a silly problem. It's a "Cat 6 flat cable".
Here is a picture of it stuck in the laptop (laptop is being held upside down):
[image: stuck cable]

Here is the picture of the other end of the cable:

[image: other end of cable]

I got it out :) but it looks completely fine. I'm not sure if I should try using it again:

[image: unplugged]
[image: unplugged]

Comment: Is the wire still attached? Can you provide a picture maybe?

Comment: @realityChemist yes it is still attached, so basically the laptop has a 50 foot cable hanging out of it

Comment: My first instinct would be to try to jimmy it out with a screwdriver, but then again my laptop is not as nice as yours. My second instinct would be to look up a teardown and see if it'd be possible to remove the plastic with the cable still there (which I'm checking now)

Comment: Did it have a locking clip that has broken off?

Comment: @DavidPostill no parts broke off. What exactly is a locking clip? It has the thin little piece of plastic at the top that snaps into place.

Comment: @Celeritas https://i.imgur.com/KoktxOh.png

Comment: @Celeritas You need to push the clip towards the cable, then pull.

Comment: @DavidPostill yes I am

Comment: @Celeritas Looks look the clip is stuck. Eventually they break (the lever part of the clip stops working) and cause problems :/ Insert a small flat blade screwdriver between the plastic and the socket and see if you can push it a bit more towards the cable.

Comment: I don't know, from the picture it looks fine. I looked at the manual and it looks like you can remove the keyboard bezel if it's really stuck, but it will be a bit involved (plan a couple hours if you've never done a teardown before). Here's the relevant manual entry: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/866656/Lenovo-G50-80.html?page=51#manual but try David's method first, it usually works and it's way easier

Comment: I got it out by pressing down on the clip using a pointed nail file. The cable looks undamaged but I'm afraid to try using it again. Will add pictures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 forces at play here, the spring of the RJ-45 locking clip, and the spring of the expanding section of your laptops ethernet jack. Unfortunately, in a market trying to make thinner laptops, useless designs such as this are fairly common.

My experience is that in addition to attempting to unspring the jack, you also need to provide a force to counter the spring in the hinged locking mechanism. in my experience with this style of hinge, I have had luck lifting a corner of the hinged section while depressing the retaining clip and pulling, although often some amount of rotation is needed to properly disengage.

Additionally, it is not uncommon for the retaining clip to hinge in a less than useful way, requiring pressure to be applied flush to the edge of the port and occasionally to push the jack further into the port to disengage the hinged protection piece.

An aside, all of my laptops that have had this design, I use a USB to ethernet adapter as the connection is more reliable, and it is a lot easier to remove.

Comment: Answering a question that has been answered in a duplicate question is not a good answer, vote to close the question instead.

Comment: @Moab the other question should have more tags so that it turns up in searches.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this happen before and like a previous contributor mentioned, it happens when the spring action of the clip has lost flex and/or when it partially breaks.

In my case I took a small set of needle nose pliers and while pushing the connector in (like you are trying to insert it), I grabbed the release with the pliers and pulled the clip down and out (toward you).

It's critical that you start by pushing the connector toward the front of the laptop before pulling on the clip with the pliers.  Use the pliers on the clip to remove the plug by pulling it down and toward yourself.

Comment: Answering a question that has been answered in a duplicate question is not a good answer, vote to close instead, if you cannot vote to close upvote the duplicate comment please.